# Plotly : dynamic title for each pie date

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pie-chart

I need help for this problem, I passed all last week on it and I didn't find the solution:

I tried to make a dynamic pie chart with a "Total" title of the pie for each date present in my dataframe.

I have succeed to make a pie chart for each date in the dropdown menu with the "visible" option, but I'm block on the dynamic title with the total which change for each pie visible.

**Here a picture of what I want to do:**

*Pie chart with dropdown menu and dynamic title*
[image: chart]

**Here the dataframe structure:**

[image: Dataframe structure]

**DL Link of Data in csv (for testing the code):**

https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20220801IDAIzPJ5

**And here the code:**

```
import plotly.express as px

config = {'displaylogo': False}
most_recent_date = data['date'].max()
date_dernier_mois = [most_recent_date]
default_date = str(date_dernier_mois)[2:-2]

# simplify - use value_counts() on whole dataframe
df_vc = data.value_counts()
# create a figure for each date
figs = {
    c: px.pie(df_vc.loc[c].reset_index(), values="Valeur", names="Type_usage", 
             labels="Type_usage", 
             title=(f"<b>Total : {df_vc.loc[c].reset_index().Total.unique()} </b>"), 
             hover_data=['Total']).update_traces(
         name=c, visible=False, hovertext = "Unite : kWh", pull = 0.05
         )
         for c in df_vc.index.get_level_values("date").sort_values(ascending=False).unique()
}

# integrate figures per date into one figure
defaultcat = df_vc.index.get_level_values("date").unique().sort_values(ascending=False)[0]
fig = figs[defaultcat].update_traces(visible=True)
for k in figs.keys():
    if k != defaultcat:
        fig.add_traces(figs[k].data)
 

# finally build dropdown menu
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": k,
                    "method": "update",
                    # list comprehension for which traces are visible
                    "args": [{"visible": [kk == k for kk in figs.keys()]}],
             
                }
                for k in figs.keys()
             ],
             "direction": "down", "x": 0.07, "y": 1.15, "bgcolor":'#1F2F40', 
             "bordercolor":"#1F2F40"
        }
    ]
 )






 fig.update_layout(autosize = True)
 fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
 fig.update_layout(
           title={
           'x':0.5,
           'xanchor': 'center'
        })
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', 
font=dict(color='#CACFD3'))
fig.update_traces(textinfo='label+percent', textfont_size=12)
fig.show(renderer="colab")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also post the data here, so people can try your code?

Comment: @jkhadka I have edited the post and added the csv DL link as you asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A title must be added as an argument to the button. The following describes only the configuration part of the button.

```
#finally build dropdown menu
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": k,
                    "method": "update",
                    # list comprehension for which traces are visible
                    "args": [{"visible": [kk == k for kk in figs.keys()]},
                             {"title": (f"<b>{k} Total : {df_vc.loc[k].reset_index().Total.unique()} </b>")} # update
                            ],
             
                }
                for k in figs.keys()
             ],
             "direction": "down", "x": 0.07, "y": 1.15, "bgcolor":'#1F2F40', 
             "bordercolor":"#1F2F40"
        }
    ]
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !
You have really unblocked me on this issue :)
I fixed the square brackets problem with a str()[1:-2], that's perfect :)